# Selenium WebDriverException 'chromedriver.exe' needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to use selenium for a python web **scraper** but when I try to run the program I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/xxx/Documents/Python/hello.py                                     
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 1702, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/xxx/Documents/Python/chromedriver.exe'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxx/Documents/Python/hello.py", line 9, in <module>
    wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Here is the python code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
from selenium import webdriver


DRIVER_PATH = '/Users/xxx/Documents/Python/chromedriver.exe'

wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
```

I think the problem is that I'm not specifying the file path in the variable DRIVER_PATH properly but I'm not sure

**I am using a Mac**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update `DRIVER_PATH` to include your root directory, which is usually `C:\`:

```
DRIVER_PATH = 'C:/Users/xxx/Documents/Python/chromedriver.exe'
```

Alternatively, you can follow this tutorial to add the path to containing folder of `chromedriver.exe` (usually chromedriver_win32 folder) to your `Path` environment variable:

https://docs.telerik.com/teststudio/features/test-runners/add-path-environment-variables

Comment: Does the tutorial also show how to do it for mac? Because my root directory is Macintosh HD instead of C: but since there is a space in between, i was wondering how I can put it into the variable

Comment: The process is slightly different for Mac -- I would use this Mac-specific tutorial instead: https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/

Answer (score 2):

I would try this out (Just adding the 'r'):

```
wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'/Users/xxx/Documents/Python/chromedriver.exe')
```

if you think it's the filepath then have a go with checking:

```
import os.path
os.path.exists(DRIVER_PATH)
```

Also, Beautifulsoup is used will with urllib2
https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/beautifulsoup/beautifulsoup-4-python

```
import urllib2
url = "https://www.URL.com"
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
```

Comment: Its printing false even though chromedriver.exe is in the python folder

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in the name of the file.

"chomedriver.exe" is for windows.

If you use macOS and chromedriver for Mac, then the file name should be "chomedriver" without ".exe".

I had the same problem, but this solved it.